# Style.color = "blue" is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my application i have a problem that the heading color is not changing. I have my code here:

```
    var createc = function(){

        var valu = prompt("Phone no.");
        var name = prompt("Name");
        var age = prompt("age"); 

        var CC = function(valu, name, age){
        var parent = document.createElement("div");
            parent.id = valu;
            parent.setAttribute("onclick", "info()");
        var heading = document.createTextNode("phone no: "+valu+" Name:"+name+" Age: "+age);
            heading.style.color = "blue";
        parent.appendChild(heading);    

        var ele = document.getElementById("main");
        ele.appendChild(parent);

        }(valu, name, age);

    }
```

here you can see in the line `var heading = document.createTextNode("phone no: "+valu+" Name:"+name+" Age: "+age);` i have a variable now in the next line i have written `heading.style.color="blue";` which i think is correct! and if i am not please tell me what the mistake i have done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`heading` is a TextNode, only ElementNodes have a `style` property.

Put the TextNode in a suitable ElementNode (since it is a heading, an `Hn` is probably the best bet) and style that.

```
var heading = document.createElement('h1');
heading.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode("phone no: "+valu+" Name:"+name+" Age: "+age)
);
heading.style.color = "blue";
```

As a rule of thumb, however, it is better to write your styles in a stylesheet and create suitable elements (with suitable classes if needed) to match the rules you've written there.

i.e. put `h1 { color: blue; }` in your stylesheet instead of using the last line in the code above.

Comment: what if i try to style a prompt value such as ` var x = prompt("name"); x.style.color = "blue" `

Comment: Strings are even further removed from anything that can be styled than text nodes. No, only elements may be styled.

Comment: in this only i try to put `\n` in text node but it was not working, is there any another way!